# Flash banner ad: need image to change upon rollover

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am creating a banner ad using Flash that consists of two images. I need the second image to display upon mouse rollover, then go back to first image upon mouse rollout. How do I do this simply using Actionscript 3 in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `ROLL_OVER` and `ROLL_OUT` [MouseEvents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html).

In the handlers for those events [remove](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild()) the old image from the display list and [add](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()) the new one.